# Unordered and repeating indexes in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[x test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXFLL.png) [X train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nPZK.png) [y train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmL3o.png) We are currently doing a project on indoor positioning system. We are currently using KNN for predicting the positions.
The code written is as follows

```
# Function to return the list of distances of the test records from train records
def distNeighbours(X_train,Y_train,X_test,K):
    distance=[]
    for i in range(len(X_train)):
        eDistance=0
        for j in range(len(X_train.columns)):   
                eDistance+=round(np.sqrt(pow((X_train.iloc[i,j]-X_test[j]),2)),2)
        distance.append((eDistance,i,Y_train.iloc[i]))
        distance=sorted(distance, key=lambda x: x[0])[0:K]
    return distance
def predictOutputNumeric(X_train,Y_train,X_test,K):
    neighbours=[]
    responses=[]
    for i in range(len(X_test)):
        neighbours.append(distNeighbours(X_train,Y_train,X_test.iloc[i,:],K))
    for i in neighbours:
        mean=0
        for j in i:
            mean+=j[-1]
        mean=mean/K
        responses.append(mean)
    return responses
```

When the Test data is double labeled, we get a output as a list of pandas series which when converted to dataframe we got index values which are unordered and some are repeating. We are still not aware which part of the code has mistake as the index is confusing.
[Output which we are getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4D57.png)
[Sample data which we are using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfSe9.png)

Comment: Can you share some data? It would make it much easier to understand the problem

Comment: And by the way, you know there is a KNN regressor implemented in `sklearn`, right? Docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html)

Comment: Yes,I know there is a knn regressor in sklearn but this is for my school project they demanded us to build all algorithms which we are using for project from scratch .That's why we are not using sklearn for this

Comment: OK, got it. Please share a sample of your `X_train`, `Y_train`, `X_test` datasets then

Comment: yeah now i have added the data

Comment: Please don't share data as pictures, just copy-paste a small sample into your question as text